# Where to place an activation function(s) in the architecture of a neural network?

Tags: python, csv, neural-network

For a perceptron, the documentation on activation functions is clear – if the predicted label of the model does not match the true label of the model – the weights update. However, there is no good documentation on how to use an activation in a neural network. *Where does one put the activation function(s) in code?* My current method was to allow each node to be an activation function – so it multiplies the previous nodes by weights and adds them together.

```
#Train Neural Network

#Input layer

#Upload csv file
#Input Variables
x0 = float(input())
x1 = float(input())
x2 = float(input())

#Weights
w0 = 0.5
w1 = 0.5
w2 = 0.5

#Nodes
n0 = (x0 * w0)
n1 = (x1 * w1)
n2 = (x2 * w2)

#Hidden layer
#Weights
w3 = 0.5
w4 = 0.5
w5 = 0.5
w6 = 0.5
w7 = 0.5
w8 = 0.5
#Nodes
n3 = ((n0 * w3)+(n1*w4))
n4 = ((n1 * w5)+(n2*w6))
n5 = ((n0 * w7)+(n2*w8))

#Output layer
#Weights
w9 = 0.5
w10 = 0.5
w11 = 0.5

#Nodes
n6 = ((n3*w9)+(n4*w10)+(n5*w11))
print(n6)

#Update
#if n6 < 0.5:
    #Update weights
#else:
    #next input
```

I understand there are a lot of questions and answers on this - but my question has not been answered. Indeed, I am asking specifically - is there an activation function associated with each layer, or with each node. Further, the documentation is unclear whether the activation function is designed to move information through the network, or to signal a weight update - both functions are required, but syntactically clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The activation function is related with each node in the network. The values travel through the synapses or connections where they are multiplied by the weights. These multiplied values are then activated using a activation function.
2. In your case, you need to activate the n0, n1 and n2 values. You can use sigmoid, tanh and ReLU.
3. Activation functions are designed to carry signals and not weight values. For example ReLU : if the input is a positive number then the signal = input but, if the input is negative then the signal = 0.
4. Activation functions are needed. They help the network to actually learn. A network with no activation functions would act as a network with a single layer even if it has multiple layers.
5. They add non linearity to the computations. Hence, an function could be approximated by them.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: Follow up question: you said I need to activate the n0, n1, n2 values and  activation functions carry signals. So, are the activation functions - functions taking the node value as input?

Comment: Activation functions take the node's value as the input. The initial value of the node is set to a random number. It gets multiplied by the node's weight value and then gets activated by the activation function.